# Optimising a node join query

Tags: sql

I have a database of nodes and ways. A way contains two or more nodes. Some nodes belong to multiple ways, and are thus termed a "join" between two or more ways.

I'm trying to find all the nodes which join two or more ways. So I'm using this query,

```
SELECT * 
FROM way_nodes wl 
JOIN way_nodes wr 
ON wr.node_id = wl.node_id AND wr.way_id != wl.way_id
```

The way_nodes table contains the list of nodes in each way.

However it's hideously slow on my database with 9,021 ways and 43,706 nodes, and only gives me 20-30 nodes per second.

Initially I tried keeping counts of the number of times a node is used, but that still takes a long time.

I'm using SQLite3, but I suspect my problem applies to all databases. How would such a query be optimised?

Comment: Do I understand this Query correctly? Find nodes that share the nodeID but not the way_id?

Comment: Find way_nodes sharing the same node_id. The goal is to get the two different way_id's. way_nodes contains a node_id and a way_id.

Comment: Is it faster or slower when you run it with the join clause of just "wr.node_id = wl.node_id"

Comment: It's more or less the same speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way to find  to find all the nodes which join two or more ways would be to count the distinct ways per node - like so:

```
SELECT node_id, count(distinct way_id)
FROM way_nodes
GROUP BY node_id
HAVING count(distinct way_id) > 1
```

Comment: Wow, it's something like 10000x faster, it completes in under a second! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you create indexes?

Comment: Yes, indexes created where appropriate.

Comment: On all the fields mentioned in the query.